# VS 2012 bundling - CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch

Tags: css, visual-studio-2012, bundle

VS 2012 automatic bundling of javascript and css seems like such a good idea. There are difficulties though like the css might just not show up. It is different in different browsers, but I finally got this message in IE - "CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch". That makes sense if you look at the page source.

```css
<link href="/Content/themes/base/css/cssbndle" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Nowhere does it say `type="text/css"`.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance, Mike

PS. Other trip ups with bundling to know about...

1. Bundling is not necessarily automatic in the release version. You may have to force it in Global.asax.cs with: `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; /// Forces Bundling`
2. Do not name the bundle the same as a css file in the bundled directory or it will fail.
3. Put the css bundle file in the same directory as the css source if you want relative links to resources to work.

I'll add this in response to Mr Lister. cssbundle is a file created by the Web Server. Works this way in IIS or the VS 2012 Server. ... So I changed the name to cssbundle.css... The Web Server is not refreshing either page.

Now note that the page source for this page (call it Page 1) that is failing shows the link:
    [link href="/Content/themes/base/css/cssbndle" rel="stylesheet"/>
If I go to the next page (call it Page 2) where it seems to be working, it shows 
    [link href="/Content/themes/base/css/cssbndl?v=MOEXz2scvEX_A3RwM4cEFqTO71EPznDGxsaHCF71UBg1" rel="stylesheet"/>

If you turn off bundling, you see the CSS files listed in the BundleConfig.cs file

```
[link href="/Content/themes/base/css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
[link href="/Content/themes/base/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
[link href="/Content/themes/base/css/calendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
[link href="/Content/themes/base/css/calendar_green.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
[link href="/Content/themes/base/css/tables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
[link href="/Content/themes/base/css/media.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
[link href="/Content/themes/base/css/css1.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Actually though, I see that if I turn off bundling, it turns it off for page 2, but not Page 1. That might be the entire problem. the bundle for Page 1 is not being refreshed. You can "force" bundling on. How do you force it off or force a refresh? That may be the whole problem.

Comment: Browsers usually don't barf on links that don't include `type="text/css"`. It's the file type of the resource itself that matters. Is this local on your computer? If so, what does Windows say the type of the file `cssbndl` is?

Comment: A quick test shows that when the file type is OK, all the browsers (FF, Chrome, IE9, Safari, Opera) load it fine, even if there's no `type="text/css"` in the link. If the file type is not OK, but the link does have `type="text/css"`, it will load in most browsers, but not in Opera. So, file type is more important.

Comment: Well FF simply doesn't seem to see the file. IE is the one that gave the message that"CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch". Chrome seems to have found the CSS, but is almost completely ignoring it. There are two images on the page, from the same directory. It is displaying one and not the other. Now note that the page source for this page that is failing shows the link: